# Reading a tiff image with c++

Tags: c++, tiff

I'm trying to get information from a tiff image file. The output of Endian is correct but the rest of them are all wrong. The first 8 bytes of the tiff file is:

```
4d  4d  00  2a  00  02  03  60
```

The magicno I'm getting is 10752, which is 2A00 is HEX. But I should be reading the third and for bytes, which should be 002a. Need help please!!

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buffer[3];

    short magicno;
    int ifdaddress;
    short ifdcount;


    ifstream imfile;
    imfile.open("pooh.tif",ios::binary);

    imfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    imfile.read(buffer,2);
    imfile.read((char*)&magicno, 2);
    imfile.read((char*)&ifdaddress, 4);

    imfile.seekg(ifdaddress, ios::beg);
    imfile.read((char*)&ifdcount, 2);

    imfile.close();

    buffer[2]='\0';


    cout<<"Endian: "<<buffer<<endl;
    cout<<"Magic: "<<magicno<<endl;
    cout<<"IFD Address: "<<ifdaddress<<endl;
    cout<<"IFD CountL "<<ifdcount<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

My output is:

```
Endian: MM
Magic: 10752
IFD Address: 1610809856
IFD CountL 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the endianness marker correctly but you do not *act* upon it. From Adobe's "TIFF 6":

> Bytes 0-1:
>   The byte order used within the file. Legal values are:
>   “II” (4949.H)
>   “MM” (4D4D.H)
>   In the “II” format, byte order is always from the least significant byte to the most significant byte, for both 16-bit and 32-bit integers. This is called little-endian byte order. In the “MM” format, byte order is always from most significant to least significant, for both 16-bit and 32-bit integers. This is called big-endian byte order.
>   (https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf)

You need two sets of routines to read a short integer from a TIFF file (and also to read the longer integral types): one that reads Motorola ("MM") big-endian numbers, and one that reads Intel ("II") little-endians.

As it is, you must be one a little-endian system while attemtping to natively read big-endian numbers.

The code to correctly read a word can be as simple as

```
unsigned char d1,d2;
imfile.read (&d1,1);
imfile.read (&d2,1);
if (magicno == 0x4949)
   word = d1 + (d2<<8);
else
   word = (d1<<8)+d2;
```

Untested, but the general idea should be clear. Best make it a functionl because you need a similar setup for the "LONG" data type, which in turn is needed for the "RATIONAL" datatype.

Ultimately, for TIFF files, you may want a generalized `read_data` function which first checks what data type is stored in the file and then calls the correct routine.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know what my problem is. I have another question. If what I read from the tiff file is  hex, why am I printing out decimal numbers?

Comment: Also, can you please explain to me the line word = d1+(d2<<8)? I don't really understand the part d2<<8. Thanks

Comment: @user2817869 The << is one of the bitwise operators. You'll want to know about them in detail if you're writing code like this. One place to start would be: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: @user2817869: but there is no spoon, I mean "hex". "Hexadecimal" is just a *representation* of a certain (abstract) number, just like the notation `10` is. You are reading *bytes*, which can have a value from 0 to 255, and which can be *interpreted* as -128 to +127, or as an ASCII character. The bytes themself are not 'in hex' or 'in decimal'.

Comment: I tried to do word = (a<<24)+(b<<16)+(c<<8)+d; for a for bytes number but did not work...How show I change this?

Comment: @user2817869: well, what's wrong with the result you got? You got the correct idea for a long number in big endian order. You need to make sure the intermediate values `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all unsigned. If you keep on having problems, post a new question with your results, just like this question.

Comment: @user2817869: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Mapping_multi-byte_binary_values_to_memory